# How to connect two IMU in one arduino board?

Tags: arduino-mega, mpu6050

The code below works fine when  one IMU (MPU9250). What I want to know is how can I edit this code to work perfectly with two IMU (MPU9250) in one arduino board ?

Hope someone can help me. THANKS :)

```c
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      //
      //  This file is part of RTIMULib-Arduino
      //
      //  Copyright (c) 2014-2015, richards-tech
     //
     //  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person           obtaining a copy of 
    //  this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in 
    //  the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, 
   //  copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the 
   //  Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, 
   //  subject to the following conditions:
   //
   //  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all 
  //  copies or substantial portions of the Software.
  //
  //  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, 
  //  INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A 
  //  PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT 
  //  HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION 
  //  OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE 
  //  SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

  #include <Wire.h>
  #include "I2Cdev.h"
  #include "RTIMUSettings.h"
  #include "RTIMU.h"
  #include "RTFusionRTQF.h" 
  #include "RTPressure.h"
  #include "CalLib.h"
  #include <EEPROM.h>

  RTIMU *imu;                                           // the IMU object
  RTPressure *pressure;                                 // the pressure object
  RTFusionRTQF fusion;                                  // the fusion object
  RTIMUSettings settings;                               // the settings object

  //  DISPLAY_INTERVAL sets the rate at which results are displayed

  #define DISPLAY_INTERVAL  300                         // interval between   pose displays

 //  SERIAL_PORT_SPEED defines the speed to use for the debug serial port

 #define  SERIAL_PORT_SPEED  115200

  unsigned long lastDisplay;
  unsigned long lastRate;
  int sampleCount;

  void setup()
  {
  int errcode;

  Serial.begin(SERIAL_PORT_SPEED);
  Wire.begin();
  imu = RTIMU::createIMU(&settings);                        // create the    imu object
  pressure = RTPressure::createPressure(&settings);         // create the  pressure sensor

  if (pressure == 0) {
  Serial.println("No pressure sensor has been configured - terminating"); 
    while (1) ;
   }

   Serial.print("ArduinoIMU10 starting using IMU "); Serial.print(imu-   >IMUName());
   Serial.print(", pressure sensor "); Serial.println(pressure->pressureName());
   if ((errcode = imu->IMUInit()) < 0) {
   Serial.print("Failed to init IMU: "); Serial.println(errcode);
   }

   if ((errcode = pressure->pressureInit()) < 0) {
   Serial.print("Failed to init pressure sensor: ");  
   Serial.println(errcode);
   }

   if (imu->getCalibrationValid())
   Serial.println("Using compass calibration");
   else
   Serial.println("No valid compass calibration data");

    lastDisplay = lastRate = millis();
    sampleCount = 0;

    // Slerp power controls the fusion and can be between 0 and 1
    // 0 means that only gyros are used, 1 means that only accels/compass are used
   // In-between gives the fusion mix.

   fusion.setSlerpPower(0.02);

   // use of sensors in the fusion algorithm can be controlled here
   // change any of these to false to disable that sensor

    fusion.setGyroEnable(true);
    fusion.setAccelEnable(true);
    fusion.setCompassEnable(true);
    }

     void loop()
     {  
     unsigned long now = millis();
     unsigned long delta;
     float latestPressure;
     float latestTemperature;
     int loopCount = 1;

      while (imu->IMURead()) {                                // get the latest data if ready yet
      // this flushes remaining data in case we are falling behind
      if (++loopCount >= 10)
         continue;

      fusion.newIMUData(imu->getGyro(), imu->getAccel(), imu->getCompass(), imu->getTimestamp());
      sampleCount++;
      if ((delta = now - lastRate) >= 1000) {
      Serial.print("Sample rate: "); Serial.print(sampleCount);
      if (imu->IMUGyroBiasValid())
      Serial.println(", gyro bias valid");
      else
      Serial.println(", calculating gyro bias");

        sampleCount = 0;
        lastRate = now;
       }
       if ((now - lastDisplay) >= DISPLAY_INTERVAL) {
        lastDisplay = now;
       //          RTMath::display("Gyro:", (RTVector3&)imu->getGyro());  
                  // gyro data
        //          RTMath::display("Accel:", (RTVector3&)imu->getAccel()); 
                     // accel data
       //          RTMath::display("Mag:", (RTVector3&)imu->getCompass());  
          // compass data
        RTMath::displayRollPitchYaw("Pose:",   (RTVector3&)fusion.getFusionPose()); // fused output

        if (pressure->pressureRead(latestPressure, latestTemperature)) {
            Serial.print(", pressure: "); Serial.print(latestPressure);
            Serial.print(", temperature: ");         
        Serial.print(latestTemperature);
        }
        Serial.println();
        }
        }
        }
```

EDITED CODE:

```
       #include <Wire.h>
       #include "I2Cdev.h"
       #include "RTIMUSettings.h"
       #include "RTIMU.h"
       #include "RTFusionRTQF.h" 
       #include "RTPressure.h"
       #include "CalLib.h"
       #include <EEPROM.h>

       RTIMU *imu;                                           // the IMU object
      RTPressure *pressure;                                 // the pressure object
      RTFusionRTQF fusion;                                  // the fusion object
      RTIMUSettings settings;                               // the settings object

      //  DISPLAY_INTERVAL sets the rate at which results are displayed

      #define DISPLAY_INTERVAL  300                         // interval between   pose displays

     //  SERIAL_PORT_SPEED defines the speed to use for the debug serial port

     #define  SERIAL_PORT_SPEED  115200

    unsigned long lastDisplay;
    unsigned long lastRate;
    int sampleCount;


    // ================= MPU: 1 =================



   RTIMU *imu1;                                           // the IMU object
   RTPressure *pressure1;                                 // the pressure object
   RTFusionRTQF fusion1;                                  // the fusion object
   RTIMUSettings settings1;                               // the settings object


   unsigned long lastDisplay1;
   unsigned long lastRate1;
   int sampleCount1;


   const int CS_MAX = 2;
   const int CS[CS_MAX] = { 7, 8 };



   void setup()
   {
  for (int i = 0; i < CS_MAX; i++) {
  pinMode(CS[i], OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(CS[i], HIGH);
  }

  int errcode;

  Serial.begin(SERIAL_PORT_SPEED);
  Wire.begin();
   imu = RTIMU::createIMU(&settings);                        // create the imu object
  pressure = RTPressure::createPressure(&settings);         // create the pressure sensor

  if (pressure == 0) {
  Serial.println("No pressure sensor has been configured - terminating"); 
  while (1) ;
   }

   Serial.print("ArduinoIMU10 starting using IMU "); Serial.print(imu->IMUName());
   Serial.print(", pressure sensor "); Serial.println(pressure->pressureName());

  for (int i = 0; i < CS_MAX; i++) {
  digitalWrite(CS[i], LOW);
  if ((errcode = imu->IMUInit()) < 0) {
  Serial.print("Failed to init IMU: "); Serial.println(errcode);
  }

  if ((errcode = pressure->pressureInit()) < 0) {
  Serial.print("Failed to init pressure sensor: "); Serial.println(errcode);
  }

  if (imu->getCalibrationValid())
    Serial.println("Using compass calibration");
  else
    Serial.println("No valid compass calibration data");

  lastDisplay = lastRate = millis();
  sampleCount = 0;

   // Slerp power controls the fusion and can be between 0 and 1
   // 0 means that only gyros are used, 1 means that only accels/compass are   used
  // In-between gives the fusion mix.

  fusion.setSlerpPower(0.02);

  // use of sensors in the fusion algorithm can be controlled here
  // change any of these to false to disable that sensor

   fusion.setGyroEnable(true);
   fusion.setAccelEnable(true);
   fusion.setCompassEnable(true);
   digitalWrite(CS[i], HIGH);
   }


   int errcode1;
   Serial.begin(SERIAL_PORT_SPEED);
   Wire.begin();
   imu1= RTIMU::createIMU(&settings1);                        // create the imu object
   pressure1 = RTPressure::createPressure(&settings1);         // create the pressure sensor

    if (pressure1 == 0) {
    Serial.println("No pressure sensor has been configured - terminating"); 
    while (1) ;
    }

    Serial.print("ArduinoIMU10 starting using IMU "); Serial.print(imu1->IMUName());
    Serial.print(", pressure sensor "); Serial.println(pressure1->pressureName());

    for (int i = 0; i < CS_MAX; i++) {
    digitalWrite(CS[i], LOW);


    if ((errcode1 = imu1->IMUInit()) < 0) {
    Serial.print("Failed to init IMU1: "); Serial.println(errcode1);
    }

    if ((errcode1 = pressure1->pressureInit()) < 0) {
     Serial.print("Failed to init pressure sensor1: ");  
     Serial.println(errcode1);
     }

     if (imu1->getCalibrationValid())
    Serial.println("Using compass calibration");
    else
    Serial.println("No valid compass calibration data1");

    lastDisplay1 = lastRate1 = millis();
    sampleCount1 = 0;

    // Slerp power controls the fusion and can be between 0 and 1
    // 0 means that only gyros are used, 1 means that only accels/compass are used
    // In-between gives the fusion mix.

    fusion1.setSlerpPower(0.02);

   // use of sensors in the fusion algorithm can be controlled here
   // change any of these to false to disable that sensor

     fusion1.setGyroEnable(true);
     fusion1.setAccelEnable(true);
     fusion1.setCompassEnable(true);


     digitalWrite(CS[i], HIGH);
     }
     }

     void loop()
     {  
     unsigned long now = millis();
     unsigned long delta;
     float latestPressure;
     float latestTemperature;
     int loopCount = 1;

      while (imu->IMURead()) {                                // get the   latest data if ready yet
      // this flushes remaining data in case we are falling behind
      if (++loopCount >= 10)
        continue;

       fusion.newIMUData(imu->getGyro(), imu->getAccel(), imu->getCompass(), imu->getTimestamp());
        sampleCount++;
        if ((delta = now - lastRate) >= 1000) {
        Serial.print("Sample rate: "); Serial.print(sampleCount);
        if (imu->IMUGyroBiasValid())
            Serial.println(", gyro bias valid");
        else
            Serial.println(", calculating gyro bias");

        sampleCount = 0;
        lastRate = now;
        }
        if ((now - lastDisplay) >= DISPLAY_INTERVAL) {
        lastDisplay = now;
        //          RTMath::display("Gyro:", (RTVector3&)imu->getGyro()); 

         // gyro data
         //          RTMath::display("Accel:", (RTVector3&)imu->getAccel());

         // accel data
        //          RTMath::display("Mag:", (RTVector3&)imu->getCompass());                 
        // compass data
          RTMath::displayRollPitchYaw("Pose:", 
          (RTVector3&)fusion.getFusionPose()); // fused output

         if (pressure->pressureRead(latestPressure, latestTemperature)) {
            Serial.print(", pressure: "); Serial.print(latestPressure);
            Serial.print(", temperature: ");   
            Serial.print(latestTemperature);
        }
        Serial.println();
        }
        }



       unsigned long now1 = millis();
      unsigned long delta1;
      float latestPressure1;
      float latestTemperature1;
      int loopCount1 = 1;

      while (imu1->IMURead()) {                                // get the latest data if ready yet
      // this flushes remaining data in case we are falling behind
      if (++loopCount1 >= 10)
        continue;

      fusion1.newIMUData(imu1->getGyro(), imu1->getAccel(), imu1-  >getCompass(), imu1->getTimestamp());
      sampleCount1++;
      if ((delta1 = now1 - lastRate1) >= 1000) {
        Serial.print("Sample rate: "); Serial.print(sampleCount1);
        if (imu1->IMUGyroBiasValid())
            Serial.println(", gyro bias valid");
        else
            Serial.println(", calculating gyro bias");

        sampleCount1 = 0;
        lastRate1 = now1;
    }
    if ((now1 - lastDisplay1) >= DISPLAY_INTERVAL) {
        lastDisplay1 = now1;
      //          RTMath::display("Gyro1:", (RTVector3&)imu1->getGyro());                   
      // gyro data
      //          RTMath::display("Accel1:", (RTVector3&)imu1->getAccel());                 
      // accel data
      //          RTMath::display("Mag1:", (RTVector3&)imu1->getCompass());                 
        // compass data
        RTMath::displayRollPitchYaw("Pose1:", (RTVector3&)fusion1.getFusionPose()); // fused output

        if (pressure1->pressureRead(latestPressure1, latestTemperature1)) {
            Serial.print(", pressure: "); Serial.print(latestPressure1);
            Serial.print(", temperature: "); Serial.print(latestTemperature1);
        }
        Serial.println();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Before editing the code to support an additional MPU9X50 you will need to figure out a way to address them on the I2C bus. Hopefully the MPU9X50 module you are using has a pin named AD0.

There are two basic solutions to multiple MPU9X50.

The first solution is to use the two different addresses. AD0 pin LOW on one and AD0 pin HIGH on the other. The sketch above would require two instances (imu), one for each module/address.

The second solution, which works for several modules, is to hold the AD0 pin LOW for the module that is addresses and all other HIGH. The setting must be handled by a digital pin. One for each module. They will be used as chip/module select. Below the example code assumes that the MPU I2C address is with the lowest bit LOW.

In the setup() initiate these pins to output mode and high. The example code uses pin 7 and 8.

```
const int CS_MAX = 2;
const int CS[CS_MAX] = { 7, 8 };

void setup()
{
   ...
   for (int i = 0; i < CS_MAX; i++) {
     pinMode(CS[i], OUTPUT);
     digitalWrite(CS[i], HIGH);
   }
   ...
}
```

Set the digital pin LOW for the module you want to address before calling an MPU library function and back to HIGH afterwards.

```
digitalWrite(CS[0], LOW);
imu->someMemberFunction();
digitalWrite(CS[0], HIGH);
```

If several functions are called in a block it can be convenient to run all of them per module. An example section from the setup:

```
for (int i = 0; i < CS_MAX; i++) {
  digitalWrite(CS[i], LOW);

  if ((errcode = imu->IMUInit()) < 0) {
    Serial.print("Failed to init IMU: "); 
    Serial.println(errcode);
  }

  if (imu->getCalibrationValid())
    Serial.println("Using compass calibration");
  else
    Serial.println("No valid compass calibration data");

  digitalWrite(CS[i], HIGH);
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much ! :) I really appreciate you . Yes , my MPU has ADO. Please see the above edited code if that is what you mean . When I upload the code the value of MPU1 n MPU2 are almost same even if I just move one of the MPU . Please guide me . Thanks :)  By the way where should I place this code   "    digitalWrite(CS[0], LOW); imu->someMemberFunction(); digitalWrite(CS[0], HIGH);             "

Comment: How can I declare tha address in the exmaple code above? thank you

Comment: Check RTIMUSettings. It contains the I2C address.

Comment: I already edit that but still no luck . :( i put MPU9250 0x69  but still the same result , is that what you mean ?

Comment: It should be 0x68 if you are going to do chip select with a LOW assert. Also the AD0 pin should be tied low. The alternative solution is to tie AD0 low on one and high on the other. They are then addressed 0x68 and 0x69 and will need two instances of the settings (imu).

Comment: I know it's too much for you to do this can you please show me how to do it ? If it's okay to you . Because i don't really get your point, THANKS :))

Comment: I got what you mean , It's now working ! Thank you so much! :)